# Monitor going logs on the screen

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, monitoring

Is there a linux command which I can use to monitor a log file? For example there is a command `top` and when I execute it I can see the recent changes of CPU usage, Memory usage and so on. Is there some similar command to use to watch the changes of some log file?

I can use `tail -500 myFile.log`, but every time I have to execute it to see the recent changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
tail -f myFile.log
```

I need to supply more text, but I don't really know what else to write, so I'm just typing random garbage here.